# How do i run an sqlite3 file/database in sqlite?

Tags: sql, sqlite

im trying to run an sqlite3 file in sqlite3 (sp500.sqlite3) but i cant seem to get it working. I initially opened it up in notepad because i wanted to look at the schema, but when i opened it, it looked like this:

> `ÿúôîèâÜÖÐÊÄ¾¸²¬¦ š”Žˆ‚|vpjd^XRLF@:4-&
>   ~`

Does that mean that its been corrupted or something? Its not just one line either its all like this. When i try to run it in sqlite3 its reading the stuff ive posted above and not the actual database information. How do i open this file as an sqlite3 file? thanks.

Comment: That's some kind of binary data, not SQL queries.

Comment: Why did you tag this `mysql` if it's about SQLite?

Comment: Is that stuff at the very beginning of the file?

Answer (score 0):

This does not look like a SQLite database  since according to your description it is missing the magic string `SQLite format 3` at the beginning of the file. I don't know where you got the file from but it might be compressed or encrypted and this layer has to be removed before you can use the file as database.